# Confidence interval for ratio between two values without confidence intervals

Tags: r, confidence-interval, ratio

I have two numeric variables (death rates), each without confidence intervals, and I want to calculate the CI of the ratio between the two values.

I was using the MOVERR method developed by Donner & Zhou but this was only applicable to values with confidence intervals.
https://rdrr.io/cran/pairwiseCI/man/MOVERR.html (This is the information on the function and package)
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20826501/ (This is the link to the article)

Is there a way to calculate the ratio's CI from two values without CI, using `R`?

An example would be the annual average mortality rate of A virus = 2.2 and the annual average mortality rate of B virus = 12.2 and I want to calculate the ratio of A against B with a 95% confidence interval.

Thank you

Comment: Please full reference to Donner & Zhou.

Comment: htmlhttps://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20826501/